# .NET Object execution

Tags: c#, powershell, events, event-handling

I am tackling a problem with event handling in PowerShell and I would like to know whether someone experienced the same.

Here is the problem:
In our Test Automation we are registering actions to .NET Object event. Registration goes fine, all actions are succesfully registered, however when we call the event, it does not fire when we expect. Below is the code:

First we call a CmdLet in powershell script:

```
Run-Test
```

Inside of the CmdLet we do the following:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Wrapper -EventName OnStepExecuting -Action {
Log-Info "test code in registered"} -ErrorAction "Stop"

Log-Info "Registration done."
$Wrapper = New-Object "OurNamespace.OurObject"
$Wrapper.NotifyOnStepExecuting()
{Some more code}
```

Inside of the C# class it looks like this

```
public event Action<string> OnStepExecuting;
public void NotifyOnStepExecuting()
{
    if (OnStepExecuting != null)
    {
        OnStepExecuting();
    }
}
```

and the output looks like this:

> Registration done.
>
> Output from *Some more code*
>
> test code in registered

To sum it up, object event runs after the **Run-Test** CmdLet is finished. However we would it to fire right when it is called. Is it possible?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33278492) may help you.

Comment: Actually, if event always called synchronously from PowerShell pipeline thread, then you better to use `$Wrapper.add_OnStepExecuting({EventHandler})`, than messing up with `Register-ObjectEvent`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this option. It seems viable. :)